# gcc compile error

Tags: gcc

I built a cross compiler on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit for MIPS platform before. but now I can't compile ordinary C programs with GCC. i removed and reinstalled everything but every time i get this error. 
as:

```
unrecognized option '--32'
```

With `gcc --version` I get this:

```
 GNU assembler 2.13.2 Copyright 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public License. This program has absolutely no warranty. This assembler was configured for a target of `mips-dec-ultrix42'.
```

i dont know what to do!

Comment: What about `gcc-4.8 --version` and `/usr/bin/gcc --version`?

Comment: That's odd. Did you somehow name the binary of the assembler `gcc` instead of `as`.

Answer (score 0):

First find the compiler:

```
find ${PATH//:/} -name 'gcc*'
```

create a symlink:

```
cd /usr/bin/
ls -l | grep gcc
ln -sf gcc-4.xx gcc
```

Now check version again:

```
gcc --version
```